# tikzexternalize and includegraphics that containning a standalone file

Tags: standalone, tikz-external, includegraphics

Because I have to include a lot of plots I want to externalize my tikz figures. But also because I like to work with `standalone` when I create the tikz figures, I would like to combine both. But I get errors when I compile.

If I remove the `tikzexternalize` library, everything is working fine.
If I change `\includegraphics` to `\input` it also works but it is not exactly the same result (and less flexibility).

I don't know how to solve this problem, and if it is possible I would like to keep the combination `standalone` and `includegraphics` because it gives me a lot of flexibility.

**MWE:**

plot.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{pgfplots}                  
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]           
        \addplot+[domain=0:0.8, samples=75, mark=None]
            {x*0.6*4.725};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{standalone}             
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{external}       
    \tikzexternalize
%   \tikzset{external/system call={
%               pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
%               -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
%           }}
%\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     


\begin{document}

        \tikzset{external/remake next=true}
        \begin{figure}
            \pgfplotsset{width=0.5\linewidth,}
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{plot.tex}
            \caption{test}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also tried, to change the compilation options but I was not able to remove the error. Any help or idea would be great.

Comment: I doubt very much that it would work. Both standalone and tikzexternalize are rather complicated code and combining both is not something I would do. Write a command that calls `pdflatex plot.tex` and then use `\includegraphics{plot}` to input the pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `standalone` and `external` combine fine. It is the addition of `\includegraphics` which is problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already include the `standalone` package in your main file, you can use `\includestandalone`. It takes the same options as `\includegraphics` and some additional ones. Most important here is the option `mode`, which will set the way the plot is generated. For example, `mode=buildnew` will build an external PDF, but only if the tex file is newer than the PDF. And `mode=tex` will include the file, i.e. no separate PDF is generated. With the latter you can use `\pgfplotset` in your main file to change the plot. With the first this is not possible, but it saves compile time. There are more modes, which may be of interest (see `standalone` manual page 25).

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}             

\usepackage{pgfplots}                  
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[mode=buildnew,width=0.9\linewidth]{plot}
        \caption{test}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \pgfplotsset{width=0.5\linewidth,}
        \includestandalone[mode=tex,width=0.9\linewidth]{plot2}
        \caption{another test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

plot.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{pgfplots}                  
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]           
        \addplot+[domain=0:0.8, samples=75, mark=None]
            {x*0.6*4.725};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

plot2.tex

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{pgfplots}                  
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]           
        \addplot+[domain=0:0.8, samples=75, mark=None]
            {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result, note the different sizes of the tick labels:

[image]